# Net 2.1, Angular 7, blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested

Tags: asp.net, cors

I am getting blocked by CORS policy.  I have allowed access to all in my startup.cs  This is my startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();

        services.AddDbContext<Models.StockContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("item"));

        app.UseCors(builder =>
        {
            builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials()
            .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this lines in your `ConfigureServices` part and it should work fine:

```
var corsBuilder = new CorsPolicyBuilder();
        corsBuilder.AllowAnyHeader();
        corsBuilder.WithMethods("GET", "POST");
        corsBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin();
        services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",corsBuilder.Build()));
```

Comment: I add your code to services in the correct place and app.UseCors() in the other section.  I get a 404 and then the same blocked by CORS.

Comment: did you mark your action controller with [httppost] or [httpget] ?

Comment: also in other section you have to write `app.UseCors("AllowAll")` instead of `app.UseCors()`

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

First, you need to enable CORS middleware inside `ConfigureServices()`
Second, you need to tell application to use this middleware inside `Configure()`

Example:

In `ConfigureServices()`:

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
            builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
    });
```

In `Configure()`:

```
    app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
```